# Magento 2.2 Add custom library file TCPDF

Tags: magento2.2, 3rd-party-library, tcpdf

I need to tcpdf (http://tcpdf.org/) library in **magento2.2**. I have added this library in **Magento2.1.9** in lib/internal/TCPDF folder.
In that, I have rename `tcpdf.php class to TCPDF.php` 
and `tcpdf class to TCPDF_TCPDF` and it was working fine.

But when I have used same in **Magento2.2**, it is not working and giving me error:

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'TCPDF_TCPDF' not found
```

Does any one have any idea that why there is issue with Magento new version and any solution for it ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the library and update corresponding dependencies using composer,use this composer wrapper to do so

https://github.com/LaurentBrieu/TCPDF

Just follow steps given in the readme.

Comment: Thanks, But why earlier method is not working ? Add Custom library into lib/internal and use directly when required ?

Comment: And suppose I have custom class which interact with linux based software then how can I add  where there is no composer for it?

Comment: It maybe because of the directory structure of file in master branch.

Comment: Was tcpdf.php located in lib/internal/TCPDF when you pasted the contents from zip?

Comment: Directory structure of master branch means? Mean am I using old magento2.2 ?

Comment: No I meant that for TCPDF , but as it was working for previous magento versions , so it will be unlikely

Comment: Is the directory structure of the current installed library same as the one you set up before?

Comment: Yes Directory structure is same as previous version. What is for custom library class created by our own ? How can we include it ?

Comment: How can I add without composer in Magento2.2 ?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your original issue

Comment: Ajay please share ans if solved, looking to add TCPDF without composer.

Comment: is it solve issue?

Comment: It solves the issue, but you need to use composer.